# using Guice with akka Props - Appropriate actor constructor not found

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, guice

I have kafkaProducer actor:

```
class KafkaProducerActor @Inject()(
  avroProducer: MyKafkaProducerAvro,
  jsonProducer: MyKafkaProducerJson,
  metrics: PrometheusMetricsService
)
  extends Actor
{
  def handleErrs(block: => Unit): Unit = {
    try {
      block
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        Logger.error(s"failed to produce kafka message, error: ${e.getMessage}, cause: ${ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e)}, stacktrace: ${ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e)}")
        metrics.incKafkaErrorCounter(e.getClass.getName)
    }
  }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case rec: ProducerRecord[GenericRecord, GenericRecord] =>
      handleErrs(avroProducer.produce(rec))

    case ProducerRecordJson(topic, key, content) =>
      handleErrs(jsonProducer.produce(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, key, content)))
  }
}
```

Also, i'm trying to use actorSystem to get the actorRef:

```
  val kafka: ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(KafkaProducerActor.props, name = "kafkaProducerActor")
```

For that i defined in KafkaProducerActor:

```
object KafkaProducerActor {
  def props: Props = Props(classOf[KafkaProducerActor])
}
```

which Warns the following:

> Appropriate actor constructor not found  Dynamic invocation could be
> replaced with a constructor invocation

when replacing dynamic invocation with a constructor invocation (as compiler suggest) i.e:

```
object KafkaProducerActor {
  def props: Props = Props(new KafkaProducerActor())
}
```

I get compilation error:

> Unspecified value parameters: avroProducer: MyKafkaProducerAvro, jsonProducer: MyKafkaProducerJson, metrics: PrometheusMetricsService

what is the right way to initiate the Props in this situation?

Comment: Does this post help? https://abhsrivastava.github.io/2017/11/03/Actors-With-Guice/

Answer (score 0):

You should inject your services in the context where you call `KafkaProducerActor.props` and just pass it as parameters.

Or just inject it manually into the constructor but you will need a static global injection for that. You can achieve it with helpers like that:

```
object InjectHelper {
    lazy val injector: Injector = {
        val moduleInstance: com.google.inject.Module = ??? // somehow get  your guice module
        Guice.createInjector(moduleInstance)
    }

    def inject[T](implicit mf: Manifest[T]): T =
        InjectHelper.injector.getInstance(mf.runtimeClass).asInstanceOf[T]
}

object KafkaProducerActor {
  def props: Props = Props(
    new KafkaProducerActor(
      InjectHelper.inject[MyKafkaProducerAvro],
      InjectHelper.inject[MyKafkaProducerJson],
      InjectHelper.inject[PrometheusMetricsService]
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: i also thought of the first solution you proposed, aiming for cleaner code I'm trying the second solution but getting compilation error: "Type mismatch. Required: MyKafkaProducerAvro Found: Class[MyKafkaProducerAvro]"
can you overcome this?

Comment: @ALjazzguitar yeah, sorry, I wrote it wrong before. I have fixed my mistake.